python: сконвертировать .ps в .jpg
Я сохранил нарисованное на canvas в postscript-файл с помощью встроенной функции postscript(). Вот код:
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
Can=Canvas(bg="white",width="900",height="900")
Can.create_oval(70,70,90,90,fill="blue")
Can.postscript(file="pos.ps",colormode="color")
Can.pack()
root.mainloop()

И этот postscript-файл пытаюсь преобразовать в рисунок JPG или GIF с помощью python, используя ghostscript и библиотеку wand. Вот код преобразования
from tkinter import *
from wand.image import Image

with  Image(filename="pos.ps") as img:
    img.format= "png"
    img.save(filename="png_file.png")

Вроде преобразовал, но файл, который получилсz в результате преобразование ps в png пустой. Почему файл, который получился - пустой?

К чему эти множественные откаты версий?

Я просто не понял роботу этого. Форума  капаяс что то намутил

А можешь помочь с вопросом которыи  которыи выложел?

Вариант, который у меня сработал (без использования .ps):
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageGrab

def save():
    x = root.winfo_rootx() + canvas.winfo_x()
    y = root.winfo_rooty() + canvas.winfo_y()
    x1 = x + canvas.winfo_width()
    y1 = y + canvas.winfo_height()
    ImageGrab.grab().crop((x, y, x1, y1)).save("Image.png")

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=300, height=300)
canvas.create_rectangle(50, 50, 150, 150, fill="blue")  # Пример рисования на холсте
canvas.create_rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200, fill="green")  # Пример рисования на холсте
canvas.pack()

button = Button(text="Сохранить", command=save)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
button.grid(row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()


ImageGrab посмотрю что это такое,  в интернете,   а во втором варианте при сохранении состояние холста ты используешь текстовую переменную и его значение  в качестве  имени создаваемого фаила postscript, напрямую писать имя фаила  или через переменную делать чте это меняет ?

Про вторую, как это решает  мою проблему? А так я пробовал преобразовать Ps в рисунок с твоим  этим кодом    image = Image.open(ps_file)
image.save("my_canvas.jpg", format="JPEG") результат такои же создаётся пустот фаил , единственное при созранени состояние холста , в ps ,я не использовал строковую переменную

Второй вариант требует установленного Ghostscript. Извините, этот вариант, как оказалось, таки фуфло полное. Я его убираю из ответа вообще. А вот первый - то, что надо, просто и изящно.

Мои часть кода которыи преобразует ps в  рисунок, работает , я беру другои ps фаил которыи например сконвертирован онлаин конвертом , и из этого ps получается ,создать графически формат, рисунка ,,проблема в ps фаиле созданным встроеннои функциеи python

postscript созданным функциеи can.postscript(file=,," grah.ps") не получется  преобразовать в другои формат рисунка ,  точнее получается но  результат конвертации это пустои фаил, библиотека wand ,и ghostscript вроде работает

Вам именно решение нужно или обязательно чтоб по-Вашему? Что проще - предварительно инсталлировать и далее поддерживать на компе Ghostscript, далее создать .ps,, а потом из него делать .png или сразу, в одной функции сделать из содержимого Canvas .png? Делайте как Вам удобно, но скорее всего потом, когда-нибудь кто-то будет переписывать эти Ваши избыточные танцы.

Да первыи вариант сгодится  но хотелось  бы понять  почему не работает postscript() , хотел бы разобратся ,может в будущем пригодится
